How can I tell from Spectrograph how song is tuned in Hz?
Part A and Part B is the same song but tuned differently. For exampled tuned to 440 Hz.
How can I mathematically take the sound (or image) to know what frequency it was tuned to? If can't quantify then atleast which is lower or higher quality.
The song has different words and sounds throughout, so does that mean I need to take some average and range, then compare the variability of the two songs?
Thank you


A spectrograph is not a useful tool for music, other than getting a visual representation of amount of energy in various frequency buckets, and identifying overtones or noise.
You cannot measure the quality of the original music files from this spectrograph.
Your horizontal yellow lines do indicate notes (you can see ones around 200Hz, 260Hz, 350Hz etc) but to get from that to identifying how the song is tuned is not going to be possible here.

Thank you, that's helpful.
As a follow up, is there another analysis or tool type that will be more helpful? With the goal of analyzing any audio (specifically songs, not just a consistent tune) and reverse engineering it to know which frequency it was tuned to (in measure of Hz)...
